# при нажатии Start создавался new.Date (будет начальное время) ,при нажатии Stop (добавлялось в таблицу начальное время, конечное время?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

У меня есть кнопка "Start" при нажатии на нее, должен создаваться объект `var dateBegin = new Date();`, но не добавляться в таблицу. После того, как нажму кнопку "stop", должен создаваться объект `var dateEnd = new Date();` и добавляться в таблицу объект *dateBegin* и *dateEnd*, т.е начальное время и конечное.

Все работает, только при нажатии на кнопку *Stop*, в таблицу добавляется два одинаковых значения времени, а надо, чтобы было начальное время и конечное.
Как это сделать?

[image]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="purchaseApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="purchaseController">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" ng-model="text" placeholder = "What are you working on?" />
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2" ng-controller="myCtrl">
                                        <select  class="inputProject" ng-model="project">
                                        <option value="{{item.key}}" ng-disabled="item.key==project" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.value}}</option>
                                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="secundomer" ng-model="timer" placeholder = "0 Sec" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-start" ng-click="addItem1(dateBegin)">Start</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-stop" ng-click="addItem(text,project,dateBegin,dateEnd)">Stop</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in list.items">
                    <td>{{item.purchase}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.value}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.dateBegin}} </td>
                    <td>{{item.dateEnd}} </td>
                    <td>{{item.date}} </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
var model = {
    items: [
    ]
};
var purchaseApp = angular.module("purchaseApp", []);
        purchaseApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.project="select project";
$scope.items =[
        { 
       value:"select project"
    },
    { 
       value:"timer"
    },
    {
       value:"timer1"
    }, 
];
  });

    purchaseApp.controller("purchaseController", function ($scope) {
    $scope.list = model;
    $scope.addItem1 = function (dateBegin) {
        var dateBegin = new Date(); 
    }       
    $scope.addItem = function (text, project,,dateBegin,dateEnd,date) {
        var dateEnd = new Date();
        var dateBegin = new Date(); 
           if(text != "") // если текст установлен и введено число, то добавляем
        {
            $scope.list.items.push({ purchase: text, project: project,dateEnd: dateEnd.toLocaleTimeString(),dateBegin: dateBegin.toLocaleTimeString());
        }
    }

});

var visible = true;
function addItem(text,project,date) {
    if(visible) {
        document.getElementById('btn btn-stop' ).style.display = 'none';
        visible = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('btn btn-stop' ).style.display = 'block';
        visible = true;
    }
}


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ничего не понятно. Что за кусок кода? что он предположительно должен делать? где разметка ко всему этому?

Comment: понятнее не стало, попробуй сформулировать вопрос

Comment: осталось добавить описание, что не так в добавленном коде

Comment: извините,я в первый раз здесь, не знаю что к чему

Comment: @Дмитрий, основное тут - задать вопрос. Пока тут добавлено: что надо сделать и какой-то кусок кода. Самого вопроса - нет. То есть, неизвестно чем не подходит этот кусок - может он одни ошибки показывает, а может и так все работает

Comment: @Grundy, все работает, только при нажатии на кнопку Stop, в таблицу добавляется два одинаковых значения времени, я надо чтобы было начальное время и конечное, и я не пойму как это сделать

Comment: @Дмитрий, вот как раз это описание и надо добавить в сам вопрос

Comment: @Grundy, добавил

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $scope.addItem = function (text, project,,dateBegin,dateEnd,date) {
> ```

Синтаксическая ошибка.

> ```
> var visible = true;
> function addItem(text,project,date) {
>     if(visible) {
>         document.getElementById('btn btn-stop' ).style.display = 'none';
>         visible = false;
>     } else {
>         document.getElementById('btn btn-stop' ).style.display = 'block';
>         visible = true;
>     }
> }
> ```

А это и всё, что с ним связано, удали.

Comment: все равно не то, получается,когда жму stop начальное время с конечным совпадает